# refused connection

Tags: wcf

I've put clientaccesspolicy.xml in wwwroot for a webservice running via ASP.NET dev server to use, but in Fiddler it shows me this message when trying to get at this file:

**[Fiddler] Connection to localhost failed.
Exception Text: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:51575 **

What does it mean?  How do I handle it?

Tony

Comment: Folks aren't likely to answer your questions if you don't bother to accept the answers.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you've got your server listening only on the IPv4 interface but LOCALHOST prefers the IPv6 interface.

Rather than using http://localhost/, instead use http://ipv4.fiddler/ instead.

Alternatively, turn off IPv6 support inside Tools / Fiddler Options.